# How do you add validations to devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise

I would like to add validations to the info of the tables of the user.
E.G. email must be with 6..20 or whatever
How do I add these to the Devise gem?

I know that the use is with :validatable, however i'm not sure what the options are.

should I add normal validations
`validates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer are written [here](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise).

In a nutshell:

- to interact with devise columns, edit this file: `/config/initalizers/devise.rb`
- otherwise, just add your column as `attr_accessible` and write your normal validations.